# Hash string in c#

Tags: c#, string, hash

I have a problem when trying get a hash string in `c#`.

I already tried a few websites, but most of them are using files to get the hash. Others that are for strings are a bit too complex. I found examples for Windows authentication for web like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(tbxPassword.Text.Trim(), "md5")
```

I need to use a hash to make a string that contains a filename more secure. How can I do that?

Example:

```
string file  = "username";
string hash = ??????(username);
```

Should I use another hashing algorithm and not "md5"?

Comment: in 2022 use this `Convert.ToBase64String(SHA256.HashData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mySecretString)))`

Answer (score 247):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public static byte[] GetHash(string inputString)
{
    using (HashAlgorithm algorithm = SHA256.Create())
        return algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
}

public static string GetHashString(string inputString)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in GetHash(inputString))
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Additional Notes

- Since MD5 and SHA1 are [obsolete and insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2948163/8690442) algorithms, this solution uses SHA256. Alternatively, you can use [BCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [Scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) as pointed out in comments.
- Also, consider "[salting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))" your hashes and use proven cryptographic algorithms, as pointed out in comments.

Comment: **DO NOT USE MD5 OR SHA1**, they are obsolete and insecure algorithms. Use SHA256 at the very least or even better use BCrypt or Scrypt.

Comment: See this example of using SCrypt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042977/example-code-for-scrypt-and-cryptsharp/34739165#34739165

Comment: For the more modern (secure) yet easy and compact hash creation method please look at my answer to this question

Comment: @Muh It can easily be used for checksums, because its much faster than SHA512. But indeed to store Passwords, it is not recommended, which is right.

Comment: @LuckyLikey Correct!

Comment: What does this `b.ToString("X2")` mean ?

Comment: @BilalFazlani see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750062/what-is-the-meaning-of-tostringx2

Comment: FYI It **IS** perfectly legitimate to use MD5 or SHA1 if your **not** using the hash as a **cryptographic** hash, for example as a hash of content for comparison. The advantage there of MD5 (for example) is speed of computation, that fact that they are insecure is then irrelevant.

Comment: Does it work on your machine? I test it and get compile error that the `algorithm.ComputeHash(...)` requires a stream as parameter, not array of bytes...

Comment: I have a question regarding hashing user's password: is it better to use this kind of string-to-string hash or simply use C#'s GetHashCode()? Why?

Comment: @TomCharlesZhang `GetHashCode()` was specifically designed for hash tables, hash sets, etc. You should not consider using this method outside of that scope. It is not intended to provide any security characteristics. Its only goal is to provide numbers with random distribution for non equal entries of those hash tables. There is another reason - internal implementation of `GetHashCode()` may change anytime, like with the next .NET update, so you should never store `GetHashCode()` results in db, sent over the wire, etc.

Answer (score 75):

The fastest way, to get a hash string for password store purposes, is a following code:

```
    internal static string GetStringSha256Hash(string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return String.Empty;

        using (var sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed())
        {
            byte[] textData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(textData);
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", String.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Remarks:

- if the method is invoked often, the creation of `sha` variable should be refactored into a class field;
- output is presented as encoded hex string;

Comment: `SHA1Managed` class is not very costly. it consumes about 130 bytes and initialize them to some static value, but that is all. so there shouldn't be a performance problem in most cases.

Comment: Also `SHA1Managed` is `IDisposable` and thus require to wrap its usage into a `using` block.

Comment: The purpose `Dispose` method is to clear the internal buffer. Failue to do so will be in risk of memory attack.

Comment: It should be noted that `GetHashCode` is not a cryptographically secure hashing algorithm (As asked for in the question). Use SHA256 at the very least or even better use BCrypt or Scrypt for a secure algorithm.

Comment: @EarthEngine In actual fact, you want your cryptographic algorithm to be as costly and slow as possible. This is one of the things that makes it secure!

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed when I said `SHA1Managed` is not costly, I mean its creation is not. Also, a hashing algorithm is not necessary costly. It only have to be (extremely) costly when you want to find a collision.

Comment: How to decrypt the hashed password ?

Comment: @King_Fisher - it's impossible! Hash is a one way function, information is lost. If you need to decrypt, you need to use encryption method not hashing. BTW, encrypting passwords is a bad practice.

Comment: Jeez, so what am I supposed to do?  Am I supposed to copy-paste your function into my program?! For christsake, microsoft.  "Copy-paste" is an anti-pattern.  For something so common there should be a function in dotnet.

Comment: @JohnHenckel do you want MS to put all possible usages into the library? It would weigh 1 GB. This method uses "composite" technique to build one of possible solutions. You can change Sha to MD5 or UTF to ASCII. However you like.

Answer (score 14):

All the hashing code samples here are outdated. In.NET 5, a new way of hashing data is provided to us which is double fast and does zero memory allocation. ain't that cool? You just need to use the new static `HashData(byte[])` on your favorite hashing algorithm class.

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
byte[] digest = SHA256.HashData(buffer);
```

Microsoft has a [new rule in its analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1850) to detect legacy usages and replace them with the new API.

Comment: The whole *point* of secure hashing, such as for passwords, is that it *needs* to be slow to produce the hash.  That's what provides defenses against brute forcing.  If you use a hashing algorithm that's fast to compute then it's *that much easier to break it*.

Comment: @Servy your point is correct but totally unrelated to my post.

Comment: It's not unrelated at all.  Suggesting a solution because it's super fast means suggesting a solution that's *necessarily* insecure, since it being slow is a key component of its security.

Comment: @Servy The computation time is dependent on the algorithm you choose. The legacy implementation of hashing algorithm is not performant in terms of CPU and memory. It means that under normal circumstances, they put more load on your servers unnecessarily. If you want to be secure, still you need select your algorithm wisely, but it doesn't mean you should select the poorly implemented legacy APIs.

Comment: @Servy is partially correct. For weak password hashing (say 1 to 6 chars), you want to use an slow processing algorithm such as bcrypt for optimal protection, as very little time difference in cracking a weak hashed password using SHA1 or SHA-256.
But for long/strong passwords - ideally adding in a large salt component, then fast hash rate is optimal, as the full bounds of 2^256 combinations are in play.

Answer (score 9):

I don't really understand the full scope of your question, but if all you need is a hash of the string, then it's very easy to get that.

Just use the GetHashCode method.

Like this:

```
string hash = username.GetHashCode();
```

Comment: Yes, that it what looking for. But it code is big mistake. Show write like int hash = "username".GetHasCode();

Comment: Why have you put username in double quotes? That will get the hash of the word 'username' and now what's in the username variable.

Comment: don't store values from GetHashCode, it is different for 32x and 64x

Comment: This is a bad way of creating a password hash. With GetHashCode() you can't assume that the same number will be generated of different computer. Use Sha1 hash method or something (I'll post an example later)

Comment: It should be noted that `GetHashCode` is not a cryptographically secure hashing algorithm. Use SHA256 at the very least or even better use BCrypt or Scrypt for a secure algorithm.

Comment: MSDN documentation: "The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for identical strings can differ across versions of the .NET Framework and across platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a single version of the .NET Framework. In some cases, they can even differ by application domain.

As a result, hash codes should never be used outside of the application domain in which they were created, they should never be used as key fields in a collection, and they should never be persisted." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This type of hash is not the same across machines or even versions compiled on the same machine - wont work in this context.

Comment: I also noticed that 'string.GetHashCode()' is not well distributed. I tried to fill a hashtable of 10000 items with test strings and it filled up the first 4600 completely while only sparsingly using the remaining space. So, much time is wasted looking for an empty hashtable bucket => not a good hash function at all!

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is not hashing but encryption. With hashing, you will not be able to retrieve the original filename from the "hash" variable. With encryption you can, and it is secure.

See [AES in ASP.NET with VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667887/aes-in-asp-net-with-vb-net) for more information about encryption in .NET.

Comment: yes, i think is encryption, but i just wish to compare result hash. After redirect page.

Comment: What do you want to compare the hashed filename with?

Answer (score 3):

The shortest and fastest way ever. Only 1 line!

```
    public static string StringSha256Hash(string text) =>
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? string.Empty : BitConverter.ToString(new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text))).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Another 1-Line version using StringBuilder & Linq

        public static string Hash(string value) =>  string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, b) => sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"))).ToString();

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not a major concern, you can also use any of these methods:
(In case you wanted the hash string to be in upper case, replace `"x2"` with `"X2"`.)

```
public static string SHA256ToString(string s) 
{
    using (var alg = SHA256.Create())
        return string.Join(null, alg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)).Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));
}
```

or:

```
public static string SHA256ToString(string s)
{            
    using (var alg = SHA256.Create())
        return alg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, x) => sb.Append(x.ToString("x2"))).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Secure & Encrypte Data
    public static string HashSHA1(string value)
    {
        var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
        var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
        var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: **DO NOT USE SHA1** from this link, SHA1 is an obsolete and insecure algorithms. Use SHA256 at the very least or even better use BCrypt or Scrypt.

Comment: See this example of using SCrypt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042977/example-code-for-scrypt-and-cryptsharp/34739165#34739165