# storing password textfield in database C#

Tags: entity-framework-4, passwords, password-storage

I'm trying to write a simple ASP.Net app that allows the users to log in with their username and password. I'm using an EF database in the .NET Framework 4, coding in C#. My problem is, when the user registers their details on the registration page, their password value does not save. That textfield is a password field.

How can I save the passwords actual value in the database, but keep the textfield as password? Would I need to encrypt it? I've never done encryption, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use some cryptographic algorithm to compute the hash for password string (see [Hash string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984138)). Then store it as byte array or encoded string (like hex or base64) in db.