# Asp.net email verification with activation link

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

Could someone explain to me how to send a verification email, without using asp.net usercreation wizard, i want it so that when the email is sent, it will contain a url link to activate an account

Comment: Are you using asp.net membership or your own?

Answer (score 2):

**First** Add a field to `Users` table called `RegisterGuidId` with type `uniqueidentifier`

**Second** after registration send a normal email to user with link to your activation page with new generated `RegisterGuidId`

**Third** after user redirected to you activation page use the generated guid to get user data from database

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need to do is, when the user registers generate a hash that is specific to the user (ideally something that can't be predicted by the bad guys) -> send this hash to the email that the user provided.

If you get a request with the url/hash that means he verified his account.

That's the basic idea anyway.

Comment: string hash = username.GetHashCode();

Comment: Also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984138/hash-string-in-c-sharp