# Read credentials in text file for program c#?

Tags: c#, string, file-io

This is my program, and it work correctly if i put username and password :

```
 try
 {

     var url = @"https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";
     var User = username;
     var Pasw = password;
     var encoded = TextToBase64(User + ":" + Pasw);
     var myweb = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
     myweb.Method = "POST";
     myweb.ContentLength = 0;
     myweb.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
     var response = myweb.GetResponse();
     var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
     textBox1.Text += ("Connection established with" + User + Pasw);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     textBox1.Text += ("Error connection. Original error: " + ex.Message);
```

now i want read string of texfile, split them and read username and password like this format:   username:password        .    There is my code at the moment:

```
 Stream myStream = null;
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

 openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
 openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
 openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
 openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

 string file_name = "";
 file_name = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + file_name;

 if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {

      try
      {        
           if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
           {

               using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(file_name))
               {
                    // Loop over the lines in the string.
                    int count = 0;
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                         string[] data = line.Split(':');
                         string username = data[0].Trim();
                         string password = data[1].Trim();

                         count++;
                 /*       Console.WriteLine("Line {0}: {1}", count, line);    */
               }
               reader.Close();
           }
       }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
       MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
  }
```

Comment: Will you please clarify your problem?

Comment: @rintintin Do i get it right that you catch an error in your try-catch statement? If so, please specify which error it is.

Comment: You havent' ask a question

Comment: The error is that the program don't pickup username and password from textfile

Comment: why don't you print all the lines to check whether it reads or not ? before spliting it and accessing index

Comment: Getting error with .Trim(); with solution of Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You open the file selected by the user, but then try to read from a variable file_name that is not the name of a file but the name of a well kwown folder. Perhaps you want this

```
try
{        
    if (openFileDialog1.FileName != string.Empty)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
        {
           ....
        }
    }
}
```

In this same code you use a StringReader, but instead you need a StreamReader to read from a file. [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx) takes the value passed in its constructor and return in the ReadLine call. Then you split the line at the colon but of course this is not the content of your file.

There are other problems in your code. For example, what do you do with the username and password loaded from the line? They are declared as local variables and not used anywhere, so at the next loop they are overwritten and lost.

So, a UserData class could be a possible answer

```
public class UserData
{ 
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

and declare at the form global level an

```
 List<UserData> data = new List<UserData>
```

and in your loop

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    try
    {        
        if (openFileDialog1.FileName != string.Empty)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
            {
                int count = 0;
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    UserData d = new UserData();
                    string[] parts = line.Split(':');
                    d.UserName = parts[0].Trim();
                    d.Password = parts[1].Trim();
                    data.Add(d);
                }

                // At the loop end you could use the List<UserData> like a normal array
                foreach(UserData ud in data)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User=" + dd.UserName + " with password=" + dd.Password);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         if(data.Count() == 0)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Load user info first");
             return;
         }

         var url = @"https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";
         var encoded = TextToBase64(data[0].UserName + ":" + data[0].Password);         
         .....
```

A warning note. Of course this is just demo code. Remember that in a real scenario saving passwords in clear text is a big security concern. The impact of this is relative to the context of your application but should not be downplayed. A better course of action is to store an [hashing of the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984138/hash-string-in-c-sharp) values and apply the same hashing function when you need to compare password

Comment: ok but in program it say that username,password don't exist in the current context

Comment: But how many lines are present in your file? The code above creates a list of these lines transformed in a UserData instances. Of course you need to pass the values of one of these instances to your method above. Something like `var encoded = TextToBase64(data[0].UserName + ":" + data[0].Password);`

Comment: can't. it give me error. but i would know how can run "var User = username; error like: don't exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry but without seeing the relationship between the two blocks of code of your question is not possible to resolve this problem. Could you update your question showing in which method is present the first block of code and in which method is presente the second one? Also after you retrieve the values from the file how do you call the first block of code?

Comment: Well, now it is clear. The List<UserData> data should be made public at the form global level. So you could use it in the button that initializes the gmail connection. I will update the answer

Comment: Yea but same problem: it say that "data" not exists in current context

Comment: Did you move the declaration of `List<UserData> data = new....` at the form global level ? (meaning outside any method but inside the form class code block)

Comment: Solved all. just now a little issue i think, don't know if it should be like that: var count never be used.

Comment: Tried with that:  foreach (UserData ud in data) 
                           { textBox1.Text += (ud.username + ud.password); }  and return path of file, (directory) not username and password. (in button 1)

Comment: And when start on button 2 i got an error like this (transleted fron italian, italian error:Richiesto valore non negativo e minore della dimensione della raccolta.
Nome parametro: index ): Index not included in (intervallo is pretty vague as a term) interval/range. Requested a non-negative value which is also smaller than the folder's size

Comment: Did you write the check for `data.Count() == 0`?

Comment: i copied all text in my project:  if(data.Count() == 0) (button2) 
int count = 0; (button1)

Comment: I have no idea on what is your problem. If you are willing to share and your project is not too big you could zip it and upload it on a online storage service like GDrive, OneDrive, DropBox and then share the link here. I will take a look.

Comment: Ok. however i would that program try to connect in a loop with all account on list just with press button 2. wait a moment for zip

Comment: Here it is download zip mediafire http://www.mediafire.com/download/alnbh2aoi4iz39x/forSteve.zip

Comment: I can't believe that I haven't seen it. You are using a `StringReader` not a `StreamReader`. That class takes your filename variable as its input (`C:\\tempnames.txt` for example) not the content of the file. So the code splits the `filename` string at the drive letter `C` and take it as the user name and the remainder of the filename as password. Change it to StreamReader and it reads the file correctly

Comment: it work perfectly, thanks a lot for all help steve... just a last question, if i want display result in textbox in vertically? like linebreak for all user data how do?

Comment: Now it's time to post a new question. Past midnight in Italy now....Good night and see you again on SO... Ciao.

Comment: Here new question :l nobody want answer me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888801/loop-function-by-button-c

Answer (score 1):

You are creating StringReader from `file_name` varialbe, which is (according to your code)

```
string file_name = "";
        file_name = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + file_name;
```

and points to nothere.

Also you have stream created for file being selected with `open file dialog` but you haven't use this stream.